# Large ffu files in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products\

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I had the Lumia Software Recovery Tool installed on my laptop.  I have removed it.  However, I notice some really large files that seem to be left behind.  These files are under the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products\RM-917 folder.  I have two folders under there RM-860 and RM-917.  I see that the files under RM-860 seem to be related to my Lumia 928.  There's a 040-115437_TYPE_LABEL_RM-860_BLACK_NOK928B_08.xml file under the RM-860 folder.  I'm thinking that I can delete both of these folders.  There's a couple ffu files under there that are multiple Gigs.

Thanks

Comment: Critical system files are never stored in that directory.  if the software is not installed currently you can delete files in the `ProgramData` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That are the ROMs for your Lumia Phones. If you don't want to reset the Phones again, you can delete the complete folder with all files.

Comment: What I thought.  I'm surprised uninstalling the Lumia Software Recovery Tool didn't delete them, or at least ask me if I wanted to delete them.

Comment: maybe it was user feedback to leave them in case the users want to reflash the phone. I have no idea